# How to correctly install a humbucker (electric guitar) pickup cover?

Tags: electric-guitar, pick-ups

I'm planning to cover up an open coil humbucker, with a cover that has no holes exposing the slugs, that looks something like this (it's simply easier to keep clean):

[image]

I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hv4KI4XD1io) on the subject, as far as I understand the process explained here is:

- Create a barrier between the plastic top/slugs and the cover using wax
- Insert the pickup
- Solder on both sides of the back
- Functionally we are done

**What I don't understand, is what are we trying to achieve with the wax?**

- Are we trying to prevent conductance between the cover and the slugs in the pickup?
- Or are we trying to make sure the pickup doesn't rattle in the cover (budget wax potting)?

Thanks for any info!

Comment: Is that cover non-ferrous?

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm not sure what that means? It's a normal nickel or chrome cover (without holes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal is to prevent the cover from rattling against the pickup. It's not "budget wax potting". The coils should be waxed regardless, and probably (hopefully!) already are.

I'm not sure if there is much significance in grounding the slugs or not (since you ground the cover), especially if they are hidden under the cover, so you can't touch them (touching ungrounded slugs may cause noise).